# django restrict fields in Create/Update view, with modelform

Tags: django, class, view, modelform

I have a django model form. The model have some business logic in the **model** `.clean()` method. 
I have defined a `ModelForm`, say:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Order
       fields = ('product', 'attachment', 'comments',) # more fields..
```

The problem: I want to restrict editing of some fields in update mode, while still **reusing** the form - since it has logic which should be the same for create and update. In this case, **only** the `comments`  should be allowed to be updated. (the rest should be disabled fields or not shown at all).

In template:
 I have a simple page where I display all the Orders of the user. In the same page he can add a new order, or to update an existing one.
 Both update and create uses the same form, and I have some JS code to disable the fields in update, and also sets an `<input type="hidden">` field with the selected Order `id`. (that's some tedious JS work, btw).

In my view:

```
class CreateOrder(CreateView):
   form_class = OrderForm
   def form_valid(self, form):
      order = form.save(commit=False)
      order.user = self.request.user
      order_id = self.request.POST.get('order_id')
      # Here I'm stuck, if I have an order_id, it should be an update,
      # so I should use form instance attribute,
      # but how do I restrict my fields in case of update?
```

I'm somewhat confused how should I handle this in the view, there are too much class views seems to fit - `CreateView, UpdateView, FormView`. I don't know which to choose.
I'm also confused whether I should somehow subclass the form, thus creating another form for update. I do want to apply the same form logic though.
If that's matter, my forms are submitted via ajax.

Comment: But how to I change the list of editable fields in the update form?

Comment: And I dont agree with you on the class views. Yeah they are complex, but meant to make code shorter.. Here I'd like to know the difference between create/form view